# Getting object by UID in YAG and Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, yag

I'm trying to recreate album object in my viewhelper, I would like to get album by UID or by Gallery UID but I can't figure out what model and method to use or where it is located.

I tried with this in my view helper but I didn't succed:

```
      $albumRepository = t3lib_div::makeInstance('Tx_Extbase_Object_ObjectManager')
     ->get('Tx_Yag_Domain_Repository_AlbumRepository'); /** @var $albumRepository Tx_Yag_Domain_Repository_AlbumRepository */

      $albums = $albumRepository->findByGallery(5);
```